# Separating an audio file into "N" frequencies

Tags: equalization, frequency

I'm working on an audio visualizer using Blender, and I'm wanting to separate input audio files into their respective frequencies to allow my models to react based on the amplitude at different frequencies. Is there a Python library out there that can (somewhat simply) separate an audio file into different frequencies? I'm going to be generating 12 different animations with audio files, and want to be able to decide which frequencies to separate out and whatnot.

Comment: This is a duplicate and has already been answered. Should not have been migrated here in the first place!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separating an audio file into "N" frequencies](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89190/separating-an-audio-file-into-n-frequencies)

Answer (score 1):

You can use
Scipy.signal https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html or,
Pyfar https://pyfar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html or,
Librosa